# Handling numbers within character strings in R

Tags: r, string, unique

I have the following (numbers-containing) character vector:

```
nums = c("1, 2", "1, 2, 4", "2, 4", "1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "2, 3, 5", NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

I want to set an algorithm that test if `n` subset of elements within `nums` contain `n` unique numbers and then remove those numbers from other elements. Where `n` is any number from `1` to `9`.

In the example above, as the first `3` elements contain only`3` numbers: `1, 2, 4`, these numbers should be removed from other elements. So the output would be like:

```
nums = c("1, 2", "1, 2, 4", "2, 4", "3, 5", "3, 5", NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

Note that it could be `2` elements having `2` unique numbers or `4` elements having `4` unique numbers, ... etc.

I'd like to keep the final output as a character vector of the same length as the original.

Comment: First you should turn your vector of characters into a list of numeric vectors. If you need a character vector (for some unspecified and strange reason), you should create it at the very end, after all data manipulations.

Comment: Good suggestion for the first and last steps, @Ronald. What about in between?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, u can apply something like the following:

```
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
nums = c("1, 2", "1, 2, 4", "2, 4", "1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "2, 3, 5", NA, NA, NA, NA)

# create a list within each element is a character element of nums
num_into_list <- stringr::str_split(nums, ",")

# convert to numbers
num_into_list <- purrr::map(num_into_list, readr::parse_number)

# collect unique numbers from the nth first subset of the list (example 3)
not_allowed <- unique(unlist(num_into_list[1:3]))

# filter only values on the rest of the subset that doesn't contain
# values in not_allowed vector, using a logical subsetting operation
# inside of  anonymous function (purrr shortcut to create this)   
output_list <- c(num_into_list[1:3],   # first 3 subset are the same
                 purrr::map(num_into_list[4:9], ~ .[!(. %in% not_allowed)]))

# finally convert into a chr vector
output <- unlist(output_list)
```

You can make a function with the above code if parametrize the nth first subset to create the `not_allowed` vector and the length of your vector to then reconstitute the list (in the `output_list` step indexation).

Comment: Thanks @Cristobal for the answer. The problem is that I don't know the value of n for each vector and which elements contain the `not_allowed ` numbers and the code should determine them first